# How to create an item list with a checkbox bullet head

Tags: front-end, cells

Is there a way to replace the red dot bullet head in the `Item` style cell with a `Checkbox[]`? And when I press the "Enter" key, the next item with a Checkbox bullet head can automatically generate (as shown in the screenshot mock up).[image]

@kglr has provided a nice solution. Hi Kglr. A follow-up question, how to use DateString[] as the CellDingbat? I have tried

`

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions ->  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["ItemCheckbox"], 
     CellDingbat -> CheckboxBox[False], 
     CellMargins -> {{81, 10}, {4, 8}}, 
     "ReturnCreatesNewCell" -> True, 
     StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Subitem", "*" -> "Subitem"}, 
     CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping", 15000}, 
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> 4, CounterIncrements -> "Item", 
     CounterAssignments -> {{"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}}, 
     MenuSortingValue -> 10000, FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro", 
     FontSize -> 15]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

`

The date is not changing between different items? How to fix it?

Comment: Edit the stylesheet and change the Cell Dingbat to Empty Square for the Item style.

Comment: try `CellDingbat -> 
 StyleBox[DynamicBox@DateString[], FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.7]]`

Comment: Awesome， thanks！

Comment: Hi @kglr, another question came up. How to preserve the states of the Checkbox? Right now, each time the file is opened the Checkbox is returned to the False state. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @bakerryd123, I don't know otomh how to make the checkbox states persist. I suggest you post this as a new question.

Comment: Ok, I have posted a new question here [LINK](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239215/how-to-preserve-the-checkbox-value-after-closing-the-notebook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new style programmatically for item-with-checkbox-dingbat using `Checkbox[]` as `CellDingbat` use:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions ->  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["ItemCheckbox"], 
     CellDingbat -> CheckboxBox[False], 
     CellMargins -> {{81, 10}, {4, 8}}, 
     "ReturnCreatesNewCell" -> True, 
     StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Subitem", "*" -> "Subitem"}, 
     CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping", 15000}, 
     CellFrameLabelMargins -> 4, CounterIncrements -> "Item", 
     CounterAssignments -> {{"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}}, 
     MenuSortingValue -> 10000, FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro", 
     FontSize -> 15]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

The new style is added to the Format>>Style menu.

[image]

The styling options are copied from:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Item"}]
```

[image]

Comment: WOW, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To add a new `Item` style with `Checkbox` by editing the notebook stylesheet:

1. Select Format >> Edit Styleheet from the menu to open the stylesheet notebook.
2. In the input field a the name for new style (`ItemCheckbox`)
3. Select Show Expression from the Cell menu to make the code behind the new cell visible.
4. Replace the code with

```
Cell[StyleData["ItemCheckbox"],
 CellDingbat -> CheckboxBox[False],
 CellMargins -> {{81, 10}, {4, 8}},
 ReturnCreatesNewCell -> True,
 StyleKeyMapping -> {"Tab" -> "Subitem", "*" -> "Subitem"},
 CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherNestedGrouping", 15000},
 CellFrameLabelMargins->4,
 CellChangeTimes -> {{3.8209323499254236`*^9, 3.8209323507429085`*^9}},
 CounterIncrements -> "Item",
 CounterAssignments -> {{"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}},
 MenuSortingValue -> 10000,
 FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro",
 FontSize -> 15]
```

5. Uncheck Show Expression in Cell menu and close the stylesheet notebook.

The new style is now available in `Format` menu and can be used to create itemized lists with checkboxes.

[image]

Comment: nice solution! Hi Kglr. A follow-up question, how to use DateString[] as the CellDingbat? I have tried to change `Checkbox[False]` in your code, but the date and time is not updating between different items.

Comment: @bakerryd123, you can use `CellDingbat ->   StyleBox[DynamicBox@DateString[], FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.7]]`