# How to preserve the Checkbox value after closing the notebook

Tags: front-end, cells, stylesheet

I am trying to create a to-do list style for the stylesheet. The goal is to have a `CellDingbat` that is a check box. And after pressing enter, a new cell with a checkbox `CellDingbat` should be created, just like the style Item.

Initially, I posted the question [in another thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239015/how-to-create-an-item-list-with-a-checkbox-bullet-head?noredirect=1#comment603956_239015), and with the help from @kglr I was able to create a to-do list style that has the desired behavior. Now, to make this to-do list style more practically useful, I would like the state of the `Checkbox` to be preserved after closing and re-opening the notebook. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This addition to your style definition should do what you need:

```
TaggingRules -> {"done" -> True},
CellDingbat ->  Cell[BoxData[ CheckboxBox[
    Dynamic[CurrentValue[ ParentCell[EvaluationCell[]], {TaggingRules, "done"}]
]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that I have changed is "done"->True to "done"->False, so that it the state of the Checkbox is False at the begining.

Comment: By the way, @Kuba, I didnt find any definition of CheckboxBox in the Help center, where can I find the usage of this function?

Comment: @bakerryd123 it is just a box representation of `Checkbox`, evaluate `Checkbox[]` and Ctrl+Shift+E on the output cell. See also http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html . p.s. yes `False` makes sense ofc.

Comment: @bakerryd123,  I suggest you consider accepting this answer (as it is extremely unlikely that there will be a better answer) . Re _accepting_ see the [Tour page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Accepted, I didn't know this 'accepting thing' before.